# App can't run in Monodevelop when there is a textbox on a form

Tags: c#, debian, monodevelop, raspberry-pi

I have installed Monodevelop under the debian (linux) on Raspberry Pi. I could run C# applications as well on the Monodevelop but there is a problem. When there is a textbox on the form in C#, the application can't run and close itself fastly.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced some weird situations like this. It's quite hard to help you with the information you gave but I two suggestions:

1. Compile your code using oldest .NET framework that you can (.NET 2 for example)
2. Remove "using System.Linq" and remove it from References as well.

Comment: There is a problem in System.Form.Draw I think.

Comment: Well, did you try to remove "using System.Form.Draw;" from code and remove it's reference?